# Changes in list column don't reflect in list app on page

Tags: 2013, list, list-view, content-editor-web-part

I have a list column, type "Choice" with boxes that can be ticked. For example:
**[ ] Category A**
**[ ] Category B**

If I add another option on a new line, say "**[ ] Category C**", and save my changes, I then normally should see the newly added "**[ ] Category C**" box when I add a new list item to the list, on every page on which I added that list. 

**However, it doesn't show up. At all.**
I do see the new option when I add a new list item directly from the list itself (via "Site content" > "Name-of-the-list-here"), but when I have added the list to a page as an app and try to add a new list item through that app on that page, then the new option is nowhere to be found. 
I've even gone as far as deleting the column, but it still shows up when I add a new list item on a page that has the list as an app. Even when I change the view, it won't show.
On a side note, I also noticed that when I change a view, the changes I made also don't reflect to the view on the page. Everytime I change a view, I reapply that view to the CEWP. But this time it just doesn't show the changes at all.

This is some very strange behavior that I have never encountered before, and I've been working with SharePoint 2013 since March this year and never had something like this.
**What could possibly cause this?** If it's of any help, this occurs in the production environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to give an answer to this last year, but here it is anyway.
It was indeed a corrupted list. Recreating the list as a new one solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The list forms remain the same regardless of the location from which you open them (from the list, or from a webpart inserted on a page). 
Make sure that the "app" you included in your page is the same list that you modified. You can compare the urls of forms after clicking 'New Item' to see why the forms look different.

Comment: The app I included in my page is definitely the same list that I modified. I added it four times over, just to be sure. I double-checked if I was working in one and the same subsite, and if there were no other lists with a similar name, but the problem persists. The urls of the forms are the same. Our external consultant believes this to be a corrupt list.